# With V8 JavaScript, is it possible that normal functions `yield` a value?

Tags: javascript, generator, v8, yield

I know `yield*` can be used to compose `generator`, like this

```
 function* foo() {
      yield* bar();
      yield 1;
 }
 function* bar() {
      yield 2;
 }
```

But if I have some normal function `yield` a value.

```
  function xx()
  {
      yield 1;
  }
```

v8 says

```
  yield 1;
         ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected number`
```

Does it mean that `yield` only saves the environment of a `generator`, not the full call stack and there is no way to stop and resume a normal function like generator?

I heard in FireFox(SpiderMonkey), `yield` can be used in normal function which is not compatible with ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `yield` is only available in generators. Generators are marked by `*` in ES6, which wasn't the case in the earlier SpiderMonkey implementation predating the ES6 draft. That's why you could use `yield` in a "normal" function in SpiderMonkey -- which then would not be normal at all, but actually a generator.

IOW, in either case, `yield` belongs to a generator. And it always produces a shallow, one-shot continuation (but you can delegate explicitly with `yield*`).

Comment: Thank you Andreas. I accept your answer. I am wondering why ES6 does not accept `SpiderMonkey yield` which is more powerful. Or even first class continuation in `scheme` which is even more powerful. We can easily build `V8 yield` based on `continuation` or `SpiderMonkey yield`. But it is difficult to do it in the other way around.

Comment: Because we found it preferable to make the distinction between functions and generators immediately apparent in code without having to search the whole body for an occurrence of `yield`. They are really quite different beasts, and calling them has completely different meanings. Full-blown continuations OTOH were unanimously rejected by the committee because they are _too_ powerful and break all kinds of invariants existing code on the web might assume, thereby being a security risk, among other problems.

Comment: Also note that SpiderMonkey's yield is no more powerful, it's just more subtle syntax.